# Integrate WhatsApp JQuery in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, whatsapp

I have a website (https://fasty.me) and I am trying to integrate this JQUERY based floating whatsap  button: https://github.com/rafaelbotazini/floating-whatsapp.

I have added the following code

In the body:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#myButton').floatingWhatsApp({
        phone: '+34607554218',
        popupMessage: 'Hola, como podemos ayudarte?',
        message: "Tu mensaje",
        showPopup: true,
        showOnIE: false,
        headerTitle: 'Hola!',
        headerColor: '#075E54',
        backgroundColor: '#25D366',
        buttonImage: '<img src="whatsapp.svg" />'
    });
});
```

In the header:

```
<!-- Whatsapp start-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="floating-wpp.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="floating-wpp.js"></script>
<!-- Whatsapp end-->
```

However, I can't see the button. The chrome inspector is telling me this, but I am using the exact same files from Github...

[image]

Help is really appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting the JavaScript beneath the <body> instead of the header? If the button is manipulating de HTML it is loaded to early, as there is no HTML at this point.

Comment: no difference :(

Comment: The problem is your page contains more than 1 jQuery versions (line 40 and 592). You should only use 1 version, preferably the latest version: v3.5.1 at the moment I write this comment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your Code Its Worked Fine , I think you attach script file are not proper
so you have to properly download and to use.

[image]